# Problems to load tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I installed `tidyverse` in R Studio, but I'm having a problem running it.

I ran `library("tidyverse")` but I keep getting an error.

```
error: package or namespace load failed for ‘tidyverse’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so, 6): Symbol not found: _EXTPTR_PTR
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
  Expected in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib/libR.dylib
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/Rcpp/libs/Rcpp.so
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘tidyverse’ was built under R version 4.0.2
```

I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is also encountered in installing Rcpp package and it is seems can be solved by upgrading the R version to 4.02.

Answer (score 3):

We answered that a few times. It is an unfortunate error in R 4.0.0 and R 4.0.1 which changed a minor detail about `EXTPTR_PTR`.

Upgrade to R 4.0.2 and the issue will go away.

Comment: Awesome!  Now, per StackOverflow custom, mayne "upvote" the question to signal it had value (click on the up-triangle) and in your case as the person who asked it, "accept" the answer (click on the tick mark).  That's how reward flows around StackOverflow, and you get points too for accepting.